# Display data to every <td> from Firestore using Nuxt

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, html-table, nuxt.js

how do I want to display those particular values into those particular td tag from a document in Firestore using Nuxt?

I already looking into some of the StackOverflow QnA but have not quite found the answer that I wanted.

Here is the image of the table:
[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt4H3.png)

So as you can see I manage to get the document into my app, but I want the data to be on that right column. How I can achieve this?

my HTML part:

```html
<template>
    <div id="SubPackageDetailTable">
        <h2>Sub-Packages Detail</h2>
        <table
            items="SubPackagesDetails">
            <tr>
                <th>Subcontractor</th>
                <td>{{ SubPackagesDetails.SubContractorName }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>WPC</th>
                <td>{{ SubPackagesDetails.WorkPackageContractorName }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Package</th>
                <td>{{ SubPackagesDetails.Package }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Sub-Package</th>
                <td>{{ SubPackagesDetails.Subwork }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <td>{{ SubPackagesDetails.code }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Commencement Date</th>
                <td>{{ SubPackagesDetails.CommencementDate }}</td>
            </tr>
            {{ SubPackagesDetails }}
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
```

my Script part:

```js
<script>
import firestore from "@/plugins/firebasetest";

export default {
    data: () => ({
        SubPackagesDetails: [
            {
                SubContractorName: '',
                WorkPackageContractorName: '',
                Package: '',
                Subwork: '',
                code: '',
                CommencementDate: '',
            }
        ],
    }),
    
    created() {
        this.refreshSubPackagesDetails();
    },

    methods: {
        refreshSubPackagesDetails() {
            this.SubPackagesDetails = [];
            firestore
                .collection("subsub")
                .get()
                .then(querySnapshot => {
                    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        this.SubPackagesDetails.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
                        this.loading = false;
                });
                console.log(this.SubPackagesDetails);
                });
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to make a 1to1 mapping between the name of your object and the name of the row of your table.

Comment: Hi @kissu, thanks for replying! But do you mind explaining what do you mean by 1to1 mapping, please? I'm still quite new to this so I do not really understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Actually you're already doing kinda that. You need to loop on each object of the array. Do you have a `v-for` somewhere? What is `items="SubPackagesDetails"` actually doing?

Comment: oh haha I just read article here and there, just follow blindly hoping it will work. Noted on v-for, will try to include that.

Comment: the items="SubPackagesDetails" I just follow vuetify v-data-table way of coding. It works for me for vuetify horizontally v-data-table  but when i try to implement the table vertically, it not work out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kissu, using `v-for` solved the problem. Not sure how to explain how it can work but here is how I do it. I'll put as answer in case if someone had a problem same as me.

```
         <table>
            <tr v-for="(subcontractorname, i) in SubPackagesDetails" :key="i">
                <th>Subcontractor</th>
                <td
                    >{{ subcontractorname.SubContractorName }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="(workpackagecontractorname, i) in SubPackagesDetails" :key="i">
                <th>WPC</th>
                <td>{{ workpackagecontractorname.WorkPackageContractorName }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="(packages, i) in SubPackagesDetails" :key="i">
                <th>Package</th>
                <td>{{ packages.Package }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="(subwork, i) in SubPackagesDetails" :key="i">
                <th>Sub-Package</th>
                <td>{{ subwork.Subwork }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="(Code, i) in SubPackagesDetails" :key="i">
                <th>Code</th>
                <td>{{ Code.code }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="(commencementdate, i) in SubPackagesDetails" :key="i">
                <th>Commencement Date</th>
                <td>{{ commencementdate.CommencementDate }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```